# How to Make PopUp Not Showing Again After User Close the Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow

I build website with popup. when user go to tab or exit button so the popup will show. My Question when user click the close button or submit form survey, so the popup will not show again when user go to tab or exit windows. this is my code below

```
<div class="box-download" id="showup-downloadbox" style="display:none;">
    <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>x</span>    
    <button type="submit" id="submitsurvey" class="submitsurvey" formtarget="_blank">SEND SURVEY</button>               
</div>

<script>
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var popupCounter = 0;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
    document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = "<br />X: " + e.clientX + "px<br />Y: " + e.clientY + "px";
});

$(document).mouseleave(function () {
    if (mouseY < 100) {
        if (popupCounter < 1) {
            $('#showup-downloadbox').delay(1000).show(0);
        }
        popupCounter ++;
    }
});
```

Comment: You have no cookies here. Also don't use cookies to save state. Use localStorage

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+show+popup+only+once+localStorage+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.